# Laravel Console Command Not Overlapping as Expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.2 job that runs every minute:

```
$schedule->command('bii:workorder-post-process')
    ->everyMinute();
```

It's a job that runs for several minutes on each execution, handling record locking inside the script itself.

My expectation is that the job WILL overlap and pick up additional records for processing every minute. That is the desired behavior.  However, the job will not spawn again until the first instance completes.

I suspect I am missing a parameter of some sort, but cannot find anything to allow concurrent jobs to run.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues you shall get everything you might need from here

Comment: Are you sure the logic for record locking doesn't block the command to run? If your Cron entry is setup correctly, the command should run every minute and overlap. You could try to test the record locking like this: in one terminal (console) run `php artisan bii:workorder-post-process`, and while it is still running, run the same command in another terminal and see if the two work in parallel, or if the second one is blocked.